# How to copy a lot of code to a different company

Tags: abap, sap-basis, bapi

I have a set of ZBAPI structures on a server of a company in which we developed and installed a custom application.

I am having to use a lot of the same BAPIs in the same application for a different company.

Is there any quick way in which I can move the Structure, Function Module, Business Object and the BAPI code itself from one SAP system to another?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the built-in [Change and Transport System](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/14/94fc3f8fc2c542e10000000a1550b0/content.htm?frameset=/en/14/94fc3f8fc2c542e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/b4/d0340a2d0f433cbeb69660e750d74b/plain.htm&node_id=3&show_children=false) (CTS), preferably by creating a [Transport of Copies](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/57/38e1a94eb711d182bf0000e829fbfe/content.htm) (ToC). You may also want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058828/get-abap-into-sap-system).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the transport system that requires a lot less configuration is to use [the free 3rd party tool `ZABAPGIT`](https://docs.abapgit.org/). You just need to copy&paste this report into the systems you want to exchange objects between.

The report allows you to create an "offline repository" based on any package in the system. You can then export the objects in that package as a ZIP file to your PC. You can then import the contents of that ZIP file in another system by running abapGit it in the destination system.

Alternatively you can also use abapGit via an "online repository", which uses a git server for exchanging data instead of ZIP files.