# "Install" SAP custom program in SAP System

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I've created a SAP program and I want to deploy it in another SAP system.
I know I can import the Transport Request files with the created program to the new system but I'm looking for other options.

Is it possible to "install"/import my program to another SAP system?

Regards

Comment: Sorry to ask, since I don't know SAP, but is this programming related. perhaps you should ask at

Comment: Why are you looking for other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ABAP into SAP System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058828/get-abap-into-sap-system)

Answer (score 1):

I can only think you don't want to use the transport system because the systems are not part of the same landscape? If so, you can still use the transport system, you just need to manually move the required files around.

But, there is another approach you can follow - using [SAPlink](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/saplink). It's an open source program that allows you download ABAP source, dictionary objects, etc. from one system into files and then upload them into another system. Of course, both systems will need to have SAPlink installed for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat by design, SAP is the largest OTS system available and there has to be some controls to ensure that people can not install software if they are not specifically given the authorization to do so.

Even to use SAPlink ( that mjturner suggests ) requires you to have the ability to install that software first and I doubt you will find it in very many productive landscapes so likely that wont be an option.

Assuming you have a developer authorization you can always download the source code from your development SAP system and then upload from within the ABAP editor (SE38) using utilities -> More utilities->Upload/Download. Note that this doesn't work in the class editor so cut and paste is another option.

Later.......

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to move transports from one system to another.

**1.    Moving the transport files form the directories “data” and “cofiles” manually.** 

When the transport is released in the source system SAP automatically puts the transport files into the transport directory on file system. This files easily can be copied to the second system an be imported via transaction “STMS”.

**2.    Using CAR files**

CAR files are packed files like a zip file. The contain the data and cofiles.
`car.exe -cvf packedFile.car data\R900000.XXX cofiles\K900000.XXX`
(car.exe is a SAP standard tool, XXX is the system ID)
This CAR files can be imported via transaction SAINT. This allows import files from frontend into the data and cofiles directory without direct access to the file system. After importing the file via SAINT the transport can be imported using STMS. This is be the common way to transport software to other systems outside the current landscape.

**3.    Using SAR and PAT files**

These files are more special. They allow to install software as Add-On in SAP. This is required if the program should be certified by SAP. They have to be created using the AAK (SAP Add-On Assembly Kit). Unfortunately, I have not created this files myself yet. But it seems to be very complex to get this running, because there are some checks which have to be passed. The files can be imported via transaction SPAM (upload) and SAINT (import).

**4.    abapGit**

A new option to deploy software is [abapGit](https://abapgit.org/). abapGit is a git client for ABAP developed in ABAP. So you can pull your development from a git repository directly to SAP